# Swing components inside HTML

Tags: java, html, user-interface, swing, components

Does anybody know of a pure java (ar at least cross platform) open source component/library which displays HTML which can contain swing components inside it?

All I could find were either abandoned or incomplete.

I am asking because I'm thinking about trying out approach to do use this combination for creating desktop application.

EDIT:Seems like this question is missunderstood, so let me clarify it. I basically want to create desktop application in the similar way as web. Idealy I would like browser to serve as an UI layer. That browser should allow me to embed my own compoents, eg to be able to use JTextField instead of `<input type="text">`.

Since I don't know of such easily usable browser, I was asking for a html component which will let me do it. I hop the question is clearer right now.

Comment: Don't quite get what you are trying to do, you want to have a java application, which will have a component that displays HTML, and in that HTML, you want to embed swing ? Does not compute.

Answer (score 3):

JEditorPane already supports what you want to do. It can render HTML (pretty crappily, I'll admit) and you can embed Swing components in that HTML using the <object> tag. Here is a blog post that demonstrates this technique: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2007/07/index.html

Otherwise, I don't think you have a lot of options.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is the other way around or, better, goes further than using JTextPane. As I understand the question: Marko needs a Java component that can display HTML and additionally is able to contain further Swing components. Say, there should be a new tag

```
<swing jclass="MySwingComponent" />
```

which would render that MySwingComponent class. Not sure, maybe it would also be okay to have a HTML-able Swing component that can embed further applets?

And no, I don't know of such a thing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX maybe?

Answer (score 0):

check out xhtmlrenderer: https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/

You will have to work wit it to get it to do all you want.

Answer (score -1):

I thought [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) allowed you to write a UI in terms of Java/Swing.  It would then convert it to JavaScript.  Maybe that's what you're looking for.